# Instagram: /users/user_id/followed-by doesn't return all followers

Tags: instagram

Example: http://instagram.com/axeeffect_ru - 1098 followers

/users/8278239

```
            {
                "meta":  {
                    "code": 200
                },
                "data":  {
                    "username": "axeeffect_ru",
                    "bio": "",
                    "website": "http://axeeffect.ru/",
                    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_8278239_75sq_1373540526.jpg",
                    "full_name": "axeeffect_ru",
                    "counts":  {
                        "media": 580,
                        "followed_by": 1098,
                        "follows": 1954
                    },
                    "id": "8278239"
                }
            }
```

followed_by: 1098 - ok

But /users/8278239/followed-by (with pagination) returns only 898 users. Why? Who are these missing 200 users?

P.S. I found this problem on several accounts. For example: for instagram.com/tcsbank (id = 202662190) the difference is 12166-9222 = 2944 users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably wrong because counters of `followers` and `following` place in another table that `followers` and `following` users. Some users could be deleted by `spam protection`, but counters doesn't update. Please read [official information](https://help.instagram.com/566399886839044) about this.